# Employer doesn't take word or deal seriously

Tags: communication, employer-relations, employment-agreement

I recently got hired to join a small team full time in the software department of this company.

The employer assured me of a 3-month accommodation arrangement (which in reality can be a daunting thing to do in such a city), so that in that time interval, I look for a permanent place to stay.

This arrangement was put in place for me since I'll be switching cities, plus it could help me get up and running at work without spending my early days hunting for accommodation.

I moved in on the starting date only to be told long excuses, such as 'an important meeting came up and he couldn't follow up on my accommodation'.

I had to crash at my brother's place, which because my brother allowed me, he probably is thinking my getting an accommodation is no longer urgent. It's been a month already and even releasing funds to cover a place acquired is taking forever.

Anytime I ask about the accommodation, he keeps giving unnecessary, unrelated excuses which make little sense. I gave myself a month, as in if he doesn't hold up to his word, I leave my brother's place and go back.

From my little observation, the employer is the 'more talk, less action' type which explains a lot considering after 8 months, he couldn't even ship an app it would take someone like me 2 weeks to get done.

As much as I like the workplace and environment and people I'll eventually work with, I want to show how serious getting a place is to me and hopefully get him to act and keep his word.

I explained to him I will be working from home (home from my other city) henceforth until an accommodation is acquired for me. That didn't sound too good to him. He doesn't know when to apologize when he disappoints. Heck, he doesn't even know he's disappointed and just keeps justifying himself every now and then.

How to I proceed henceforth, not putting my spot at risk, however conveying how serious my getting a place is to both me, and my productivity at work?

Comment: Is this common in your culture?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen which part common in our culture?

Comment: Sounds like he isn't going to pay for your accommodation at all, every day he can delay spending money benefits him, that's just basic economics. So you need to force the issue one way or the other.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't really make sense and all this is too vague and too much like a rant to answer, VTC.

Comment: @Lilienthal Last sentence, I mean, I'll love to be a part of the team, however I also want to convey how serious getting a place for me is, to my employer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have done the best thing by moving back home. It's really up to the boss to follow through with his promises or not. But at least this way you're more comfortable. Accommodation is not a small issue.

I think all you can do is keep pushing for it, but if you're working remotely then it's no longer an urgent matter. If he wants you on site he needs to sort his end out.